# Failure installing pybluez

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybluez

I want to install pybluez with python 3.8 but get this error:

```
C:\wndows\system32>pip install pybluez
Collecting pybluez
  Using cached PyBluez-O.22.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Could not find the Windows Platform SDK

    -----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Rostan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nx_jjne7\pybluez\
```

I tried to download it from the [PyPI - the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBluez), but the latest version is for Python 3.5 (I am using Python 3.8)

Comment: Did you try providing the Platform SDK?

Comment: I have the same problem!!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980599/3220983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is still no fix for pybluez on Windows.

Personally, I use pybluez2 and it function the exact same as pybluez.

To install pybluez 2:

pip install pybluez2

Starter/Test Code:

```
import bluetooth as bt
devices = bt.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print("Devices found: %s" % len(devices))
```