# Error downloading pybluez on windows 10 with python 3.7 (64-bit)

Tags: python, bluetooth, pip, pybluez

I was attempting to download the python module one windows 10 pybluez (using the cmd `pip install pybluez`, when I had this error:

> Collecting pybluez
>     Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/98/3149481d508bee174335be6725880f00d297afebe75c15e917af8f6fe169/PyBluez-0.22.zip
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Could not find the Windows Platform SDK
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hartenc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r9kn6698\pybluez\

After extensive research, I was still unable to figure out why it wasn't working, so any help would be very beneficial. BTW I am using python 3.7. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: Is it simply that pybluez is not compatible with python 3.7

Comment: Why should it be not compatible with Python 3.7? Rather than guessing what the reason _could_ be, post the error message to find out what the reason _is_.

Comment: The message `Could not find the Windows Platform SDK` indicates that you don't have Windows SDK installed. If you can't/don't want to mess with that, you can download the Python 3.7 wheel file from [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AOf8NdRKNfz6OAM&cid=BDF103E942F0E7D2&id=BDF103E942F0E7D2%21128&parId=BDF103E942F0E7D2%21125&o=OneUp), it has the extensions precompiled. After downloading, run `pip install path\to\PyBluez-0.22-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` to install it.

Comment: When I tried to install it using teh second of your two methods, I got the error: `PyBluez-0.22-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Also, I tried installing Windows SDK and it still gave the original error.

Comment: If you cant' install the wheel, either you don't use Python 3.7, or Windows, or 64bit. What do `pip --version` and `py -3.7 -c "from pip._internal import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_supported())"` return? If you have installed Windows SDK and you're having the _exact same_ error, then it's either not installed, or not configured correctly as the setup script doesn't discover it. Where was the SDK installed on your machine?

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate question. See my SO answer posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980599/3220983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that the location you are looking for is not hidden. In my case I had pip installed but the python directory wasn't showing up. Then make sure you have windows 10 SDK installed. You should have 19.0.3 v of pip in the python directory.
If not then check: https://datatofish.com/upgrade-pip/

Once you have correct version of pip, launch powershell/command prompt and type in:
pip install PyBluez-win10.